# This if statement isn't working - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to retrieve the access level (admin/member/guest) for the currently logged in user and depending on this, show them specific content on my page. I'm trying to test this with echos right now but still cannot get anything to print out. Could anyone give any advice?

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

    global $con;
    $q = "SELECT access FROM users WHERE username = '$username' ";
    $result = mysql_query($q, $con);

    if($result == 'guest')
    {
        echo "You are a guest";// SHOW GUEST CONTENT
    }
    elseif($result == 'member')
    {
       echo "You are a member"; // SHOW OTHER CONTENT
    }
    elseif($result == 'admin')
    {
        echo "You are an admin";// SHOW ADMIN CONTENT
    }

}
```

Comment: You have some serious SQL-injection issues.

Comment: hint: `$result` is not a string.

Comment: Did you put session_start(); at the very top of your script?

Comment: Which IF does not work? Also I'd swap the ifelses for a switch block & set guest as the default action.

Comment: `$result` won't contain the access level but a resource value. You'll have to do `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result, $con); $access = $row['access']; if($access=='guest') { ... }` in order to verify it. Also, as mentioned, SQL-injection vulnerability.

Comment: @Vivin How so? `$username` may be escaped correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$result` is a mysql resource.  you need

```
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){

    global $con;
    $q = "SELECT access FROM users WHERE username = '$username' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($q, $con);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $access = $row['access'];

    if($access == 'guest')
    {
        echo "You are a guest";// SHOW GUEST CONTENT
    }
    elseif($access == 'member')
    {
       echo "You are a member"; // SHOW OTHER CONTENT
    }
    elseif($access == 'admin')
    {
        echo "You are an admin";// SHOW ADMIN CONTENT
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks this is great, just what I was missing

Answer (score 1):

`$result` as returned by [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is *not* a string that you can compare against; it is a [resource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php). You need to fetch the row from `$result`:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)
$access = $row['access'];

if($access == 'guest') {
   ...
}

...
```

A few other issues:

- You have a possible SQL-injection issue in your query. You should never directly insert the values of variables into your SQL queries without properly escaping them first. You might want to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).
- The [`mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) is being deprecated. You should try to use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (MySQL Improved) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (PHP Data Objects).

Comment: If you're going to downvote, please explain why. But at the very least, thanks for making my rep a multiple of 5.

Comment: @alex *may* being the operative word :D It's never a good practice IMO to directly insert values into a SQL query without escaping them first.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues:
1. You need to use session_start(); at the beginning. otherwise your if statement will not be executed.
2. mysql_query($q, $con) does not return a string. it returns a record set. You need to use mysql_fetch_assoc($result); which return associative array.And from the array you retrieve your desired value by:
$assoc_arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$access = $assoc_arr['access'];

now you can compare $access.